# How do I delete all files with certain file extensions in Git/GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I have a lot of .o and .exe files that I want to delete, how would I do this in Git(Hub)?

Comment: Depends on your operating system, and is more a question for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/): [Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1091344/powershell-to-delete-all-files-with-a-certain-file-extension), [UNIX](https://superuser.com/questions/89413/delete-files-recursively-matching-a-name-on-the-command-line-os-x)

Comment: I wish if Github has a feature like file manager

Comment: If you regularly accidentally commit build artifacts such as these, then you might wanna a.) add them to your `.gitignore` and/or b.) tweak your build to generate all artifacts in a dedicated `build/` subdirectory and put *that* in your `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 2):

Git allows [pathspecs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary) in commands like [git rm](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm).

You can use those commands:

```
git rm --cached **/*.o **/*.exe *.o *.exe
```

`**/*.something` means everything ending with `.something` in a directory.

`*.something` means everything ending with `.something` in the current directory.

You might also want to add these extensions to your `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Github repository
2. Press <kbd>.</kbd> on the repo main page
3. Select all `.o` and `.exe` files then right click and delete files permanently
4. In the sidebar click on the GIT icon, add commit and push the changes

Thanks GitHub for this feature https://twitter.com/github/status/1425505817827151872

Answer (score 0):

## External alternative

You can use a tool like [git-filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch): [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/tree/main), which is [recommended by the official Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_warning).

It can be used to do exactly what you require: filtering the git log in order to remove commits that contain the `.exe` and/or `.o` files.

You only require a Python interpreter (check [the official repository](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) for further information on supported versions) and the [main script file](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/git-filter-repo). Said script must be located in your repository (no need to stage nor commit it).

Taking a quick glance at [the documentation](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html), you can determine that the only command you require to filter the files from the log is the following:

```bash
python git-filter-repo.py --invert-paths --path-glob **/*.o --path-glob **/*.exe --path-glob *.o --path-glob *.exe
```

- `python` is the reference to your Python interpreter
- `git-filter-repo.py` is the file you should have downloaded previously
- `--invert-paths` sets the behavior of the command to exclude whatever path globs you pass as arguments
- `--path-glob` sets a glob pattern to be excluded (repeated for each exclusion)

### Example usage

In my case, I needed to exclude some `.exe` files from the log. These are the commands I used for that purpose:

```bash
git clone <repo url>
cd <repo name>
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/newren/git-filter-repo/main/git-filter-repo -o git-filter-repo.py  # Get the main script file.
python git-filter-repo.py --invert-paths --path-glob **/*.exe --path-glob *.exe --force
git remote add origin <repo url>
git push --set-upstream origin <branch name> --force
```

The `--force` options used both in the `git-filter-repo` ànd `git push` calls might be necessary depending on your configuration, in my case, they were.

### Warning

Even though this alternative is safer than `git-filter-branch`, it poses huge risks for the integrity of your repository. Use it carefully and make sure to have a backup at hand just in case things go wrong.

If, by any chance, you corrupt your log, you can always reset it from a local clone of the repository that has not pulled changes on the remote. Just navigate to said clone and run `git push --set-upstream origin <branch name> --force`, which will rewrite the log again.

Comment: Note: this overwrites previous commits. This is perfectly fine if you are working alone but if not, you should take special care and inform anyone else working with the repository to re-clone it.